# Flutter : A procedure runs well in debug mode but not after release, why?

Tags: debugging, flutter, release

My project works everything fine in debug mode but After release, everything works except one procedure.

**Here is the procedure :**

```
 Future<void> downloadFile() async{
Dio dio = Dio();

var directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
await dio.download(bookUrl, "${directory.path}/$className + $bookName.pdf",
onReceiveProgress: (rec, total){
  setState(() {
    downloading = true;
    percentage = ((rec/total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0)+'%';
  });
}

);

setState(() {
  downloading = false;
  percentage = 'Download Completed';
});
```

}

**Here is the error message I've got when Release app runs :**

> E/flutter (25796): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)]
>   Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: SocketException:
>   Failed host lookup: 'www.ets.org' (OS Error: No address associated
>   with hostname, errno = 7) E/flutter (25796): #0      Dio._makeRequest
>   (package:dio/src/dio.dart:799) E/flutter (25796):  E/flutter (25796): #1      Dio._request.. (package:dio/src/dio.dart:711) E/flutter
>   (25796): #2      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132) E/flutter
>   (25796): #3      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029)
>   E/flutter (25796): #4      _FutureListener.handleValue
>   (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126) E/flutter (25796): #5
>   Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback
>   (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639) E/flutter (25796): #6
>   Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668)
>   E/flutter (25796): #7      Future._complete
>   (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473) E/flutter (25796): #8
>   _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51) E/flutter (25796): #9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.
>   (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:33) E/flutter (25796): #10
>   _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120) E/flutter (25796): #11     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021) E/flutter (25796): #12     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923) E/flutter (25796): #13     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded. (dart:async/zone.dart:963) E/flutter (25796): #14     _rootRun
>   (dart:async/zone.dart:1124) E/flutter (25796): #15     _CustomZone.run
>   (dart:async/zone.dart:1021) E/flutter (25796): #16
>   _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923) E/flutter (25796): #17     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded. (dart:async/zone.dart:963) E/flutter (25796): #18     _microtaskLoop
>   (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41) E/flutter (25796): #19
>   _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

make sure you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in your app's android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 4):

> SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'www.ets.org' (OS Error: No
>   address associated with hostname, errno = 7)

It seems you cannot connect to this host. Could it be that you need network permissions for your app?

Edit: see OP's answer below for the specific line of code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56921201/679553

Comment: I don't know about this. this is the only procedure that gives error after release.

Comment: I did. Thank you.